# List.add() method gives error in public class

Tags: java

I'm a java learner, I got a error when I instantiate list object and call add method with in a public class. The same code didn't give me any errors if put the code in main method or if I declare method as static. Below is the code snippet.

```
public class UserDao {
    //private  static List<UserBean> user = new ArrayList<>();//---->  no erros
    private  List<UserBean> user = new ArrayList<>();//--> remove static
    //static {
    user.add(new UserBean(1, "Harshit", "Madhapur"));//---->gives me error if remove comments.(static)
    user.add(new UserBean(2, "Sushil", "Hyderabad"));
    user.add(new UserBean(3, "Mohit", "Delhi"));
    user.add(new UserBean(4, "Shantanu", "Dampur"));
    //}
    public List<UserBean> findAll() {
        return user;
    }
    public UserBean getUserById(Integer id){
        for (UserBean userBean : user) {
            if(userBean.getId() == id){
                return userBean;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting ? Please add it with the question

Comment: Your list is not declared as `static`, neither are you adding elements in a static block. Add your elements in a method, not at class level.

Comment: Without the `static { }`  block, the `add()` calls are not a part of a block that can be executed - hence a compiler error. The code needs to be inside something that can be executed - a method, a constructor, an instance initialization block, or a static initialization block - depending on when it should be invoked.

Comment: proper code indentation helps understanding it - and can be a hint to the actual problem

Answer (score 1):

You cannot execute statements<sup>1</sup> outside methods or initializers.

This is not possible:

```
class A {
    System.out.println("Hello world"); // Compilation error
}
```

This is possible but is static:

```
class A {
    static {
        System.out.println("Hello world");
    }
}
```

If you want to remove the `static` here, you can, but don't remove the braces. It will become an initializer.

```
class A {
    {
        System.out.println("Hello world");
    }
}
```

This is however discouraged for reasons beyond the scope of this answer.

What you want is to execute initialization code in the constructor, which is essentially "the last" initializer<sup>2</sup>, if you had many:

```
class A {
    public A() {
        System.out.println("Hello world");
    }
}
```

<sup>1 You *can* execute code outside initializers, but only as part of a field declaration, like in `List lst = Arrays.asList("a", "b");`
2 Not really, but again, out of the scope of this answer.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

**You can't access to non-static field from static block of code**(static method or static initialization blocks). Fields available only from **non-static block of code**. This is legal:

```
public class UserDao {
    private  List<UserBean> user = new ArrayList<>();//non-static field
    {//access from non-static code block
      user.add(new UserBean(1, "Harshit", "Madhapur"));
      //skiped
    }
//skiped
}
```

But you can access **static field** from anywhere (static method,  static initialization blocks, non-static initialization blocks, non-static methods)

```
public class UserDao {
    private  static List<UserBean> user = new ArrayList<>();
    static{//access to static field from static initialization block
        user.add(new UserBean(1, "Harshit", "Madhapur"));
      //skiped
    }
    {//access to static field from non-static initialization block
        user.add(new UserBean(2, "Hars", "Shapur"));
    }
//skiped
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Static block is used for initializing static variables. That's why

```
private  List<UserBean> user = new ArrayList<>();
static {
user.add(new UserBean(1, "Harshit", "Madhapur"));
user.add(new UserBean(2, "Sushil", "Hyderabad"));
user.add(new UserBean(3, "Mohit", "Delhi"));
user.add(new UserBean(4, "Shantanu", "Dampur"));
}
```

will result in error. Whereas,

```
private  static List<UserBean> user = new ArrayList<>();
static {
user.add(new UserBean(1, "Harshit", "Madhapur"));
user.add(new UserBean(2, "Sushil", "Hyderabad"));
user.add(new UserBean(3, "Mohit", "Delhi"));
user.add(new UserBean(4, "Shantanu", "Dampur"));
}
```

will run without any error.

Answer (score 0):

Use the static block or add elements to the list after you've created the object.

```
// inside UserDao class
public void add(UserBean ub) {
    user.add(ub);
}

[...]

public static void main(String[] args) {
    UserDao user = new UserDao();

    user.add(new UserBean(1, "Harshit", "Madhapur"));
    user.add(new UserBean(2, "Sushil", "Hyderabad"));
    user.add(new UserBean(3, "Mohit", "Delhi"));
    user.add(new UserBean(4, "Shantanu", "Dampur"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As per your question, it will give error because in that case the static block will be trying to initialize a non-static member. Static reference cannot be made to the non-static field.

You can go for the following two options as per your application and further usage of the members:

1. Make the list **static** and try populating the items within static block.
2. Avoid the use of static for both of them.